# Signing an Android app in PhoneGap - where do I find the keytool file?

Tags: java, android, cmd, phonegap, keytool

I'm trying to generate a signing key via keytool for use with a PhoneGap Android app. Here's the command I'm using:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my_keystore.keystore -alias ge-app -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

And it appears to have generated the key:

[image]

Trouble is, [this rather unhelpful article](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/signing/android/) has nothing to say on where I should find the generated file in order that I can upload it to the key uploader on PG's Build website:

[image]

From [this page](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO28992.html) I learned about `keytool -list`, but when I run that I get

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction? CMD/Java are very much not my strong suits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
>   keytool -genkey -v -keystore my_keystore.keystore -alias ge-app -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

Gives you more than enough info where you stored your .keystorefile

Firstly you Changed Directory onto C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin,
so your current dir is that

Than you runned command `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my_keystore.keystore -alias ge-app -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

important line is this: `-keystore my_keystore.keystore` where my_keystore.keystore is specified path to your keystore file, since this is relative path it placed it in your current directory which is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin

If you want your keystore file to be generated in your home folder you will need to run this:

`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\Users\SuperPudding\my_keystore.keystore -alias ge-app -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Note: I'm not that much familiar with the windows paths but my guess is that it is correct command

Comment: "Gives you more than enough info where you stored your .keystorefile" - why would you think this? Why would I assume my_keystore.keystore is a path rather than just syntax? I said I wasn't familiar with this.